# create annotated tags in gitahead

Tags: git, gitahead

It seems, gitahead uses "lightweight" tags, but I want annotated tag. Is there something I have overlooked (hidden somewhere in the gui), or do we need a feature request here?

Also I really like the behaviour in HG to have a commit associated with adding a tag.

Even when this would cause e.g. to create a textfile in the root folder of a git repository, tracking tagname and commit (hash) via a commit is a missing thing in git, which at least a gui like gitahead could provide. At least even if missing, doing so by hand is error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature should be there considering [githaead code source](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/blob/7916a2700a0040ae09cdbd98ca9e056dd7d52e66/src/dialogs/TagDialog.cpp#L46-L48) (in `src/dialogs/TagDialog.cpp`)

```cpp
  QCheckBox *annotated = new QCheckBox(tr("Annotated"), this);
  ExpandButton *expand = new ExpandButton(this);
  connect(annotated, &QCheckBox::toggled, expand, &ExpandButton::setChecked);
```

It does create a checkbox for you to select, for creating an annotated tag.